# Can't run Docker inside of Windows, which is inside of VirtualBox

Tags: docker

I have a client who sent me instructions to connect to their VPN, but their VPN solution is only supported on Windows. Therefore, I'm trying to use Windows inside of VirtualBox to install Docker, so that I can pull down a container (Kali) to perform my assessment.

However, I've spent a little over 7 hours today troubleshooting. I'm trying to figure out what's wrong with either Windows or my configuration settings. I've gone from installing Windows Server 2019 in Amazon's EC2, Lightsail, Windows 10 in VMware Fusion, and now finally VirtualBox. No luck. Each of the solutions requires a lot of hacking and troubleshooting to figure out what's going on.

**Host specs:**
macOS Big Sur
2.9GHz Quad Core Intel Core i7
Memory: 16GB
Storage: 500GB flash storage

I've allocated 4GB of memory to the host, along with 2 processor cores.

As you can see in the screenshot below, Windows 10 Pro is telling me that I need to enable something, which the Optional Features window on the left shows is enabled. As you can also see on the right hand side, I have hardware virtualization enabled in the VM.

[image]

It's literally the same thing documented here: https://www.configserverfirewall.com/windows-10/please-enable-the-virtual-machine-platform-windows-feature-and-ensure-virtualization-is-enabled-in-the-bios/

Here's all the things that I've tried thus far:

**Attempt #1** (re: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5363#issuecomment-640337948)

```
dism /Online /Enable-Feature /All /FeatureName:Microsoft-Hyper-V
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto
```

Here's the output:

[image]

After rebooting and trying to fire up Docker again, the same error occurs.

**Attempt 2**: Checking BIOS

Several have suggested doing this, but I have found no way to boot into the Windows BIOS using VirtualBox. Nothing here.

**Attempt 3**: Re-enabling WSL (re: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5363#issuecomment-675786863)

Per the instructions in this comment, I have disabled WSL from the Optional Features section in Windows 10, rebooted, got an error about WSL 2 not being enabled, re-enabled WSL, rebooted again, and just ran into the exact same error.

**Attempt 4**: Disabled Hyper-V

Disabled Hyper-V and got the same error.

**Attempt 5**: Modifying the .VMX file (re: https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Fusion-Discussions/VMware-Fusion-12-1-0-Big-Sur-Host-Windows-10-Guest-Running-Slow/td-p/2814913)

However, no luck here either. Instead of the previous error, it fails with "The operation timed out because a response was not received from the virtual machine or container". I guess it got even slower.

Any new suggestions or pointers on how to resolve this?

Comment: Docker on windows is working through a VM inside your Windows VM, I'm not sure any windows guest VM allows nested virtualization.

Comment: It seems there are a lot of conflicting articles about this. Many of these articles suggest crazy workarounds, but none of them seem to be relevant or work anymore.